# Open modal on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I got bootstrap form and button and when i click on button it procees to other page, but what i need is, when i click on button, to open modal, i think preventdefault function or something like that, but i will need help for this, and this is my code

```js
var request = false;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#sonata_add_basket_submit').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (false === request) {
            request = true;
            var self = $(this);

            jQuery.ajax({type: self.attr('method'), url: self.attr('action'), data: self.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        request = false;
                        jQuery(self.attr('data-target')).html(data).modal('show');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="form_add_basket_button_{{ product.id }}" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('sonata_basket_add_product') }}" method="POST"{% if provider.getOption('product_add_modal') %} data-target="#add_basket_modal_{{ product.id }}"{% endif %}>
               
  <button type="submit" class="homecart" id="sonata_add_basket_submit" data-target="#add_basket_modal_{{ product.id }}" data-toggle="modal"{% if sonata_product_stock(product) == 0 %} disabled{% endif %}>
                    <i class="categoryicon2"></i> {% trans from 'SonataProductBundle' %}sonata.product.btn_add{% endtrans %}
                </button>

                {{ form_rest(form) }}
            </form>
```

My code is not good, where is mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the submit handler to the form, not to the button:

```
jQuery('#form_add_basket_button_{{ product.id }}').on('submit', function (e) {
```

See the API for examples and explanations: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: i change this part code, but same thing, it starting to open modal, then, process to other page like before

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #form_add_basket_button_{{ product.id }}